# Detected memory leaks en in EC_POINT_point2hex

Tags: c++, memoria

estoy escribiendo un programa para generar carteras en frio de algunas criptomonedas, el problema que tengo es que al intentar pasar la llave privada a llave publica me da una fuga de memoria, he estado bicheando por ahí códigos en c++ para secp256k1 y BIGNUM, pero algunos son muy avanzados, otros no los echo andar y el que he encontrado que medio entiendo y funciona esta escrito en C, si reservo con malloc directamente ni compila y si libero con free, vuelca.
A ver si alguien me puede explicar un poco, gracias

```
./prueba
Dirección Bitcoin: 1MqcznDoLdVGr9UfxAKvezdXP7CP4L3iYu
Llave Privada Hex: 353A7E999D69D8AE8729D4B4B4F07839088EA9C5912510B14C009B35681807B5

=================================================================
==450==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 132 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fe11a5ddbc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #1 0x7fe11a2fe552 in EC_POINT_point2hex (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1+0x10e552)
    #2 0x7fe11af5c205 in main /Generador/cpp/prueba.cpp:110
    #3 0x7fe119e070b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 132 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Este es el código que tengo el problema, comentar que la clave privada de entrada y la clave pública de salida están en hexadecimal no se si el problema será el trabajar char con hex, aunque supongo que no. la salida del generador la variable generaClave es un string, para trabajar con esa funcion en c he tenido que convertir el string a char[], he intentado generaClave pasarlo como referencia para no declarar otra variable, he intentado pasarlo a hex y pasarlo por la funcion, pero en ambos caso me sigue dando errores,
la verdad que el codigo no me gusta mucho, el echo de convertir y tener que crear variables para pasar formatos no me termina de convencer pero el unico que me funciona

```
char *priv2pub( const char *priv_hex, 
                         point_conversion_form_t form )
{
  // create group
  EC_GROUP *ecgrp = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name( NID_secp256k1 );

  // convert priv key from hexadecimal to BIGNUM
  BIGNUM *priv_bn = BN_new();
  BN_hex2bn( &priv_bn, priv_hex );

  // compute pub key from priv key and group
  EC_POINT *pub = EC_POINT_new( ecgrp );
  EC_POINT_mul( ecgrp, pub, priv_bn, NULL, NULL, NULL );

  // convert pub_key from elliptic curve coordinate to hexadecimal
  char *ret = EC_POINT_point2hex( ecgrp, pub, form, NULL );

  EC_GROUP_free( ecgrp ); BN_free( priv_bn ); EC_POINT_free( pub );

  return ret;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    // Argumentos para los diferentes bytes de red
    // Bitcoin por defecto sin argumento
    uint8_t networkByte = 0x00;
    // Litecoin
    if (argc == 2 && std::string(argv[1]) == "-ltc") {
        networkByte = 0x30;
    }
    
    std::string cPrivada_hex;
    cPrivada_hex = GeneraClave();

    char cPrivada_char_tmp[int(100)];
    strcpy(cPrivada_char_tmp,cPrivada_hex.c_str());
    char *pub_hex = priv2pub( cPrivada_char_tmp, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED ); //esta es la linea 110
    std::string hexstring;
    hexstring = pub_hex;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice el mensaje, nunca liberas la memoria obtenida con `EC_POINT_point2hex`. La línea

```
hexstring = pub_hex
```

solo copia `pub_hex`. Después de eso tienes que liberarla con `OPENSSL_free(pub_hex)`.

Comment: Prefecto muchas gracias, pero ahora la pregunta por que con  free( pub_hex ); no funciona y con OPENSSL_free(pub_hex); si? en ambos casos se libera pub_hex

Comment: No sé, tal vez `OPENSSL_free` libera otro pedazo de memoria asociado a `pub_hex` del que `free` no sabe nada. Especulación mía no más.